# Would anybody know of any resources on using Google Apps script with Jamboards?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, stickynote

I am looking to count the number of sticky notes on a Jamboard automatically as soon as someone adds one. Is there any way to do this? Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Jamboard does not support developer products.

Hence you can't use google apps script or any other google API to interact with Jamboard.

Please have a look at the [official website](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/products):

[image: example]